# How to increment a variable, like the line number, in a vscode snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have a multi-line snippet in VScode.  The problem is, TM_LINE_NUMBER gives the number of the line where the snippet was triggered, I need to increase that number by 1 so it equals the line number that it is actually on.

```
"Console_Log_Test": {
  "prefix": "clg",
  "body": [
    "//Debugging (remove)",
    "console.log('Line #${TM_LINE_NUMBER}');"
  ]
},
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least these two options:

```
"Console_Log_Test": {
      "prefix": "clg",
      "body": [
          "//Debugging (remove)",
          "console.log('Line #${1:${TM_LINE_NUMBER}}');"
          // "console.log('Line #${TM_LINE_NUMBER}');"
      ]
}
```

With the above at least the line number is selected and you could easily change it yourself.

More interesting is to make this into a "**macro**" which will accomplish exactly what you want.

1. You will need something like the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).
2. Change above snippet to :

   ```
   "Console_Log_Test": {

     "prefix": "clg",
     "body": [
         "console.log('Line #${TM_LINE_NUMBER}');"
     ]
   }
   ```

so now the snippet only prints the line with the `TM_LINE_NUMBER` in it.

3. In your User Settings:

   ```
   "multiCommand.commands": [

   {
     "command": "multiCommand.lineNumber",
     "sequence": [
       {
         "command": "type",
         "args": {
           "text": "//Debugging (remove)\n"
         }
       },
       {
         "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
         "args": {
           // "langId": "csharp",
           "name": "Console_Log_Test"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

Now the snippet is actually triggered on the line number you want.

4. In your keybindings.json:

   ```
   {
     "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
     "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
     "args": { "command": "multiCommand.lineNumber" }
   },
   ```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> does exactly what you want to do. It is a bit of work to set up but a pretty powerful method to learn.

**[EDIT]**

I was wondering if there was a way to get some **emmet** math to work and, surprisingly, it does.

Using this snippet:

```
 "log line number on second line": {
      "prefix": "clg",
      "body": [
          "//Debugging (remove)",
          "console.log('Line #${TM_LINE_NUMBER}"
      ]
  },
```

That snippet has everything but the final `');`

Now this macro:

```
{
    "command": "multiCommand.lineNumber",
    "sequence": [
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "name": "log line number on second line"
        }
      },
      "editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOne",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "');\n"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

will work!! The line number will be incremented by one and then `');\n` will be added to the end of that line.

And you can do fancier math using `"editor.emmet.action.evaluateMathExpression"` in place of the `incrementNumberByOne` command.

To add 10 to the line numbers, use

```
"console.log('Line #${TM_LINE_NUMBER}+11"
```

in the snippet and `"editor.emmet.action.evaluateMathExpression"` in place of `"editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOne"` in the multicommand macro.